# Differentiation of the Hadamard Matrix Product

Tags: hadamard-product

Thank you for taking the time to read my question. I've had a look at other posts regarding differentiation of Hadamard Products of matrices but none of the examples are the same as the one I am curious about. I am looking to do the following:

$ \frac{dL}{d\beta} $ where $L = y'(X\beta \: ⊙ \: X\beta ) $ where y is a N by 1, X is N by K and $\beta$ is K by 1. Denote $\underline{x_i'}$ the i-th row of the matrix X.

Here are my thoughts : 
$y'(X\beta \: ⊙ \: X\beta ) = y_1(\underline{x_1'}\beta)^{2}+...+y_n(\underline{x_n'}\beta)^{2}$ so its derivative for any entry $\beta_k$ in $\beta$  will be equal to $2y_1 x_{1,k}\underline{x_1'}\beta \: + \: ... +2 y_n x_{n,k}\underline{x_n'}\beta = 2<y⊙\underline{x_k}, X\beta  >$ which suggests that, in matrix form, it should be something like $2y'X ⊙ X\beta$ ? This is only my intuition.

Many thanks for any help and time you may provide.

Comment: Can you please clarify what is $y'$? Your idea seems to be generally in the right ballpark, but details are uncertain. I would think when differentiating a square there should be a factor of $2$...

Comment: Thank you. $y'$ is the transpose of the vector $y$.

Comment: Do you mean $2y'(X \odot X)\beta$? I just want to make sure how you are wanting to associate the matrix products.

Answer (score 1):

The trace/Frobenius product is $$A:B={\rm tr}(A^TB)$$
The Frobenius and Hadamard products commute with each other and themselves
$$\eqalign{
 A\odot B &= B\odot A \cr
 A:B &= B:A \cr
 (A\odot B):C &= A:(B\odot C) \cr
}$$
which allows us to write
$$\eqalign{
 L &= y:(X\beta\odot X\beta) \cr
dL &= y:(X\,d\beta\odot X\beta+X\beta\odot X\,d\beta) \cr
   &= y:2(X\beta\odot X\,d\beta) \cr
   &= 2(X\beta\odot y):X\,d\beta \cr
   &= 2X^T(X\beta\odot y):d\beta \cr
\frac{\partial L}{\partial\beta} &= 2X^T(X\beta\odot y) \cr
}$$